# Saving images to localStorage using fetch() and blob()

Tags: javascript, local-storage, blob, fetch

Unfortunately there aren't any working examples of a code mentioned in the title.
All found around were either a bit old-fashioned like canvas or too long.

```
fetch('https://www.stevensegallery.com/320/240')
  .then(pic => pic.blob())
  .then(pic => localStorage['pic'] = pic);
```

Is there any concise one-liner to do it without writing a separate function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally made it not too heavy. Also had to `JSON.parse` it before putting into actual source.

```js
fetch('https://source.unsplash.com/300x170/?girl')
  .then(pic => pic.blob())
  .then(pic => {
    const fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = () => { 
      const dataURL = fr.result;
      document.getElementById('pic').src = dataURL;
      localStorage['pic'] = JSON.stringify(dataURL);
    }
  fr.readAsDataURL(pic);
});
```

```html
<img id='pic' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a `function` which does it for you:

```
function storeImage(key, url) {
  fetch(url)
    .then(pic => pic.blob())
    .then(pic => {
      const fr = new FileReader();
      fr.readAsDataURL(pic);
    })
    .then(pic => localStorage[key] = pic);
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
storeImage('pic', 'https://www.stevensegallery.com/320/240');
```

Comment: I wasn't able to make the function body work as intended. And you?

Comment: I did not have time to test the code. Did you receive any errors?